# Proof Essential Singularities are Isolated

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone provide a proof of the fact that essential singularities must be isolated from other singularities? I keep hearing this fact, and I'm not sure what it quite means, in contrast with removable singularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the definition of "essential singularity". Some define only a certain kind of isolated singularity as "essential singularities", others call all singularities that are neither removable nor poles "essential singularities". In the former case, it's part of the definition, in the latter, essential singularities need not be isolated. For example every point on a branch-cut would be an essential singularity in the latter sense.

Comment: Haha I was just reading all of your responses to other questions on this subject.

I was defining them as the second definition, so I see then.